# How do I identify the username for my heroku token?

Tags: heroku

I have a terminal that's logged in to Heroku, but I'm not entirely sure under which userid. How do I check if it's me (as opposed to my coworker), so as to not clobber someone else's heroku app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$> heroku auth:whoami
```

will show you who you are currently authenticated as.

Comment: $ heroku auth:whoami
 !    `auth:whoami` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for additional details.

Comment: Maybe update your Heroku gem? It was added on May 10th 2012 so there's a chance you're using an old version of the gem. https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/command/auth.rb#L70